# Como solucionar ID em URL do ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

O URL do sistema estão no formato

```
http://localhost:52962/Funcionario/Edit?ID_FUNCIONARIO=7
```

Isso no meu caso é um problema, pois se o usuário alterar este 7 para 11 por exemplo, ele vai buscar o funcionário 11(que de acordo com a regra de negócio isso não deveria ser possível), alguém sabe como posso ocultar esse `ID_FUNCIONARIO` do final do URL?

Answer (score 1):

Silva. Como não sei exatamente qual é a regra de negócio que você precisa aplicar neste caso. Vou mostrar três formas de tratar o que entendi ser o seu problema. Mas já adianto que a primeira, não atende 100% do seu problema e nem é recomendada.

1 - (NÂO RECOMENDADA) Supondo que o problema seja apenas "esconder" o id do funcionário, você pode passar o parametro ID_FUNCIONARIO através de uma requisição POST. Mas como disse antes, não atende 100% do problema, pois é possível forjar uma requisição POST através de softwares como o Fiddler.

2 - Neste caso estou supondo que o seu usuário pode acessar a página ~/Funcionario/Edit/ de diversos funcionários diferentes.
Neste caso você deve validar se o usuário que fez a requisição tem permissão para visualizar a página. Você deve validar isso tanto na Action que responde para requisições Get quanto na Action que responde para requisições POST. Se você precisar fazer este tipo de validação em muitas Actions, vale a pena criar um ActionFilter para isso.
Ex. da validação no dentro do método.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID_FUNCIONARIO)
{
   var idUsuario = User.Identity.GetUserId();
   if(!ValidarRequisicao(idUsuario, ID_FUNCIONARIO))
   {
      return View("AcessoNegado"); //
   }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Funcionario oFuncionario)
{
   var idUsuario = User.Identity.GetUserId();
   if(!ValidarRequisicao(idUsuario, oFuncionario.Id))
   {
      return View("AcessoNegado"); //
   }
}
```

3 - Supondo que o Funcionário e o usuário sejam a mesma coisa e cada usuário só pode editar as próprias informações:
Neste caso, basta validar se o id do funcionário é igual ao id do usuário logado. Lembrando de SEMPRE validar tanto o GET quanto o POST. Ex:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID_FUNCIONARIO)
{
   var idUsuario = User.Identity.GetUserId();
   if(idUsuario != ID_FUNCIONARIO)
   {
      return View("AcessoNegado"); //
   }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Funcionario oFuncionario)
{
   var idUsuario = User.Identity.GetUserId();
   if(idUsuario != ID_FUNCIONARIO)
   {
      return View("AcessoNegado"); //
   }
}
```

Caso nenhuma das três opções solucionem o seu problema, coloque mais detalhes do que precisa ser validado para sua regra de negócio. Lembrando que a primeira deixa uma brecha de segurança FACILMENTE explorada.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, a melhor solução para seu problema é criptografar o valor passar e descriptografar ao receber na outra página.

http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3078/criptografando-dados-com-csharp.aspx